# Wordpress error while moving site from localhost to live server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I developed a Wordpress site on localhost and I wanted to take it live. I had my domain and host, zipped the Wordpress site file from htdocs and moved it to the host https docs, exported the database to the host in SQL format, changed the URL in wp-options table, established the connection in wp-config file, and the site showing the first page only. Other pages error 404, can't edit via elementor, can't add a new page (you are offline error). Can you help me find the error please?

Note: using Plesk as a host.

Comment: What appears in your address-bar when you get the 404 not found error?

Comment: Server Error

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: I meant the address bar, the part of your browser display where the https://... is displayed. Many CMSs like wordpress make you enter your sites domain name somewhere in the administrator's settings. It sounds like either you don't have it set to your domain name or you are waiting for the DNS system to propagate your domain name. I'm only guessing though because I don't have much information to go on.

Comment: the permalinks are right , not localhost links , but still not working

Comment: I see. Maybe there's an issue with your web-server's configuration. You could make a simple PHP file and upload it to a directory on the server which had previously given an error and see if you can access it over the web by typing its address in the address bar. Don't know what else to suggest, sorry.

Comment: Your procedure for migrating your web site from one server to another is, with respect, doomed to failure. There are just too many things to fix in your files and data when you change hostname. There are a few free  migration plugins. Use one. I like Duplicator, but there are others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access the WordPress Admin Dashboard? If yes, please go under Settings > permalinks, and try clicking Save without making any changes. This should flush the permalink settings. After that, check if it's resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that an .htaccess file exists in your document root with at least this content?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

If the file is missing, simply create a text file in your websites's document root named ".htaccess" with above content. When the file is missing and you try to use permalinks in Wordpress, only your start page can be displayed.